# ROS2 C++ cv::VideoCapture

Tags: ros2

`hi

> cam_reader.hpp
>
> #include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
> #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
> #include "sensor_msgs/msg/image.hpp"
> #include "cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h"
>
> class CamReader : public rclcpp::Node
> {
> public:
> CamReader();
>
> cv::VideoCapture cap;
>
> private:
>
> Subscribers
>
> Publishers
> rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>::SharedPtr image_publisher_;
>
> Timers
> rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr get_image_timer_;
>
> Callbacks
> void get_image_callback_();
>
> };

> cam_reader.hpp
> #include <cam_reader/cam_reader.hpp>
>
> CamReader::CamReader ()
> Node("cam_reader")
>
> char videopath[] = "/home/pi/Meurtres_au_paradis.S01E01.mp4";
> this->cap.open(*videopath);
> this->cap.open(0);
> if (!this->cap.isOpened())
> {
> RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Error opening camera");
> }
>
> get_image_timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
> std::chrono::milliseconds(2000),
> std::chrono::milliseconds(50),
> std::bind(&CamReader::get_image_callback_, this));
>
> auto default_qos = rclcpp::QoS(rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS());
>
> Force to be reliable, some DDS have set defaultQoS to best effort
> default_qos.reliable();
>
> image_publisher_ = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Image>("/image", default_qos);
> }
>
> void CamReader::get_image_callback_()
> {
> cv::Mat frame;
>
> this->cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
>
> cv_bridge::CvImage img_bridge;
> sensor_msgs::msg::Image cam_msg;
>
> std_msgs::msg::Header header; // empty header
>
> img_bridge = cv_bridge::CvImage(header, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8, frame);
> img_bridge.toImageMsg(cam_msg); // from cv_bridge to sensor_msgs::Image
>
> image_publisher_->publish(cam_msg);
> }
>
> int main(int argc, char * argv[])
> {
> rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
> rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared());
> rclcpp::shutdown();
> return 0;
> }

> It's ok with this->cap.open(0);
> but error with this->cap.open(*videopath);
> pi@pi-desktop:~/face-recognition$ ros2 run cam_reader cam_reader_node
> WARN:0@0.203] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (2401) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Cannot identify device '/dev/video47'.
> WARN:0@0.203] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1356) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
> WARN:0@0.204] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
> WARN:0@0.204] global /home/pi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (902) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video47): can't open camera by index
> [INFO] [1679388758.511573816] [cam_reader]: Error opening camera

There is no problem playing the video with a non-ROS2 c++ program and I don't understand the error on opening the video.
I have to go through c++ for face detection with DNN because python is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

In the example that I took as a basis, the opening of the video was done in the callback. But while trying to open the video I had a compilation error which disappeared with the introduction of the pointer on videopath (*videopath). Despite everything without compilation error I had the same error at runtime.
Since I transferred the opening of the video in the opening of the node. I just noticed that by removing the pointer this->cap.open(*videopath) in this->cap.open(videopath); the video worked.
So it's solved.